# I can't loop my code whenever condition fails. It just prints both blocks of code if the user input is true

Tags: java, eclipse, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I am a beginner at java and I want to loop this all over again but I don't know how. I've tried a while loop but it doesn't work really well and it prints both blocks of code. What should happen is when I type "quit, Quit, or QUIT", it should terminate. What happens instead is that it also prints the message "failed to terminate the program". What should I do? I've also tried an if statement which works fine but I don't know how to loop it if the condition fails.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class fortytwo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hi there!");
        String quit = scanner.next();
                
        while (quit.equals("quit") || quit.equals("QUIT") || quit.equals("Quit")) {
            System.out.println("You terminated the program");
            break;
        } 
        System.out.println("You failed to terminate the program.\n To quit, type (quit), (Quit), or (QUIT)");
            
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand what `break;` does. It will just break out of the loop, and then your code will continue to run after the loop. It will not quit your program. Having a loop with an unconditional `break;` is kind of pointless and defeats the purpose of a loop, as your loop will never ever actually loop and either not run at all or just break out of the loop in the first iteration.

Comment: `break` only jumps out of the loop. Do you mean `return`? Also shouldn't the `while` loop be an `if`?

Comment: I think you misunderstand what `while` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition of the loop is to check *while* `quit` is NOT equal to `"quit"` (regardless of the case), so the message `"You failed to terminate the program..."` should be printed in the loop body until appropriate command is entered.

Also, assignment to `quit` may be omitted, and the method `equalsIgnoreCase` is recommended to invoke on the constant/literal value because in general case it helps avoid `NullPointerException`.

```java
while (!"quit".equalsIgnoreCase(scanner.next())) {
    System.out.println("You failed to terminate the program.\n To quit, type (quit), (Quit), or (QUIT)");
}
System.out.println("You terminated the program");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a loop without a need for it. Also `break` only exits the loop, but continues execution after the loop. Replace the while with an if/else:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Hi there!");
    String quit = scanner.next();
            
    if(quit.toLowerCase().equals("quit")) {
        System.out.println("You terminated the program");
    } else {
        System.out.println("You failed to terminate the program.\n To quit, type (quit), (Quit), or (QUIT)");
    }
    scanner.close();
}
```

This does not prompt for input again which your second output hints at, but neither does your code.